# IDisposable and multiple-inheritance

Tags: c#, idisposable

I am using a third party class library. This implements class A that implements IDisposable and an interface B that also implements IDisposable.

I have a class that needs to inherit from class A and implemnt interface B. If a do a Visual Studio code analysis it reports that I am not implementing IDisposable correctly and to remove IDisposable from the list of interfaces.

Given that I cannot change A or B and the fact they both need to handle IDisposable. Is there a recommended way of handling this or doing I just ignore this.

External library has:

public interface IModbusMaster : IDisposable

public abstract class ModbusDevice : IDisposable

My code uses:

public abstract class ModbusMaster : ModbusDevice, IModbusMaster

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you need to inherit from both? I would hope that the 3rd party library set this up their model so that is never needed

Comment: The question is how you are going to do multiple inheritance in C# ?

Comment: Btw - you cannot inherit from both classes.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not possible by .NET. You could *implement* multiple interfaces but not *inherit* from multiple classes.

Comment: sorry class and an interface

Comment: Please add simple example what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar question here, implies a false positive that can be suppressed.

[Code Analysis CA1063 fires when deriving from IDisposable and providing implementation in base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925925/code-analysis-ca1063-fires-when-deriving-from-idisposable-and-providing-implemen)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from multiple classes in C# so you have to code your way around this with a [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

You should inherit from A (is-a) and "have" (has-a) instance of B:

```
class MyClass extends A
{
    private B instance_of_b;

    public MyClass(B instance_of_b) // constructor
    {
        this.instance_of_b = instance_of_b;
        ...
```

Your methods from B are then delegated to the instance of b:

```
    public double MethodInB(int arg1, string arg2)
    {
        return instance_of_b.MethodInB(arg1, arg2);
    }
```

This is the only chance you get to mix behaviour of more than one class and mimic multi-inheritance.

Obviously, this comes with a lot of other synchronization and management problems you'll have to tackle.

Comment: The question has been changed. It is not actual multiple inheritance.

Comment: Sorry I has a class and an interface

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll remove it later. If it's useful for some random visitor it might be better to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

If A is a class, and it *implements* IDisposable, it must provide a Dispose method. It can however provide an abstract definition (if the class itself is marked as abstract), which means that you must *override* that Dispose method when you *inherit* from that class:

```
public abstract class BaseClassFromLibrary : IDisposable
{
    public abstract void Dispose();
}

public class MyClass : BaseClassFromLibrary
{
    public override void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```